# Show countdown timer on camera in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

How to create Custom camera with Countdown Timer in Flutter.
I have tried take container under stack on camera but this Container is not showing on camera.

Comment: Just take stack and put camera as first item and text() widget as second widget. Don't wrap text with any other widget.

Comment: //This is not working
    Stack(
      children: [
        _openCamera(),
        Text(
          'Timer',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am focus only functionality check below code may this is help full for you.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

List<CameraDescription> cameras = <CameraDescription>[];

Future<void> main() async {
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    print("${e.code} ${e.description}");
  }
  runApp(CameraApp());
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  CameraController? controller;
  Timer? countdownTimer;
  Duration myDuration = const Duration(seconds: 10);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    controller?.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void startTimer() {
    countdownTimer =
        Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => setCountDown());
  }

  void setCountDown() {
    const reduceSecondsBy = 1;
    setState(() {
      final seconds = myDuration.inSeconds - reduceSecondsBy;
      if (seconds < 0) {
        countdownTimer!.cancel();
      } else {
        myDuration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller!.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    String strDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final days = strDigits(myDuration.inDays);
    // Step 7
    final hours = strDigits(myDuration.inHours.remainder(24));
    final minutes = strDigits(myDuration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    final seconds = strDigits(myDuration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              CameraPreview(controller!),
              Text(
                '$minutes:$seconds',
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: startTimer, child: const Text("Start")),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is working. Thanks!